# HTML Agility Pack - Grab Text after a node

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have some HTML that I'm parsing using C#

The sample text is below, though this is repeated about 150 times with different records

```
<strong>Title</strong>: Mr<br>
<strong>First name</strong>: Fake<br>
<strong>Surname</strong>: Guy<br>
```

I'm trying to get the text in an array which will be like

```
customerArray [0,0] = Title
customerArray [0,1] = Mr
customerArray [1,0] = First Name
customerArray [1,1] = Fake
customerArray [2,0] = Surname
customerArray [2,1] = Guy
```

I can get the text in the array but I'm just having trouble getting the text after the STRONG closing tab up until the BR tag then finding the next STRONG tag

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use XPath `following-sibling::text()[1]` to get text node located directly after each `strong`. Here is a minimal but complete example :

```
var raw = @"<div>
<strong>Title</strong>: Mr<br>
<strong>First name</strong>: Fake<br>
<strong>Surname</strong>: Guy<br>
        </div>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(raw);
foreach(HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//strong"))
{
    var val = node.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::text()[1]");
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText + ", " + val.InnerText);
}
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EPRd43)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
Title, : Mr
First name, : Fake
Surname, : Guy
```

You should be able to remove the ":" by doing simple string manipulation, if needed...

Comment: Did you ever know that you're my hero?

Answer (score 1):

`<strong>` is a common tag, so something specific for the sample format you provided.

```
var html = @"
<div>
<strong>First name</strong><em>italic</em>: Fake<br>
<strong>Bold</strong> <a href='#'>hyperlink</a><br>.
<strong>bold</strong>
<strong>bold</strong> <br>
text
</div>

<div>
<strong>Title</strong>: Mr<BR>
<strong>First name</strong>: Fake<br>
<strong>Surname</strong>: Guy<br>
</div>";

var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
// 1. <strong>
var strong = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//strong");
if (strong != null)
{
    foreach (var node in strong.Where(
        // 2. followed by non-empty text node
        x => x.NextSibling is HtmlTextNode
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.NextSibling.InnerText.Trim())
        // 3. followed by <br>
        && x.NextSibling.NextSibling is HtmlNode
        && x.NextSibling.NextSibling.Name.ToLower() == "br"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", node.InnerText, node.NextSibling.InnerText);
    }
}
```